# Query runs fast on Oracle but very slow in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, oracle, query-optimization

I've been working on procedure conversion from Oracle to Postgres and have encountered a performance issue.
So it took 15 seconds to run this query on Oracle and 35 minutes to run it on Postgres

```
select count(*)
from DATA_BUFFER a
LEFT OUTER JOIN NETWORK_LINES n 
ON n.ROUTE_NAME = trim(substr(a.SIGNED_HIGHWAY_ID, 0, 7));
```

Tables in Oracle and Postgres have same amount of records and this query returned the same value

Comment: There are *so* many differences in how database engines work under the hood, and potential differences in your hardware, configuration, and SQL optimization for each, that there's really no way to tell *why* one is faster than the other based on this tiny amount of information. The only advice I would have is to apply appropriate tuning techniques to Postgres and see if you can get it faster.

Comment: Do EXPLAIN on each system and compare them.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: Do you have the same indexes defined in both databases?

Comment: In some sense you are lucky. To get a query from 35 minutes to 15 seconds is usually a straightforward task. A *simple join* query that *should* end in 15 seconds but takes *ages* in most case uses *nested loop* followed with a *inappropriate index access* instead to make a *full scan* of both tables followed with a *hash* join. Simple check the *explain* as recommended in other comments. You may also post the sizes of your tables, because they must be *non trivial* to generate a 35 minutes performance.

Answer (score -1):

Your postgres `DATA_BUFFER` table may benefit from an [index on the expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) you use in your ON clause.

Try this:

```sql
CREATE INDEX trimmed_highway_id ON 
    DATA_BUFFER (trim(substr(a.SIGNED_HIGHWAY_ID, 0, 7)));
```

This may remove the need for running a mess of string-handling operations to satisfy your LEFT JOIN.

(This is a guess: you didn't give us details of your tables and indexes, and details are everything when optimizing queries.)